# how to block my website and make invisible/under-construction view for specify state of county

Tags: php

how to block my website and make invisible/under-construction view for specify state of county
Example: I want to block my website in Country-UK / State-London
mean no buddy can see home page of website they see under-construction page

Please give me a solution for that, I would prefer PHP programming for that, but if you have a better option please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to use IP-to-Location mapping, which is called geolocation.

Comment: that and know that it is easy to get around if some one wants to

Comment: It's easy or not. It's doable. Still, it's rather the only way.